# setVisibleCoordinateBounds never set the exact Bounds

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

i'm struggleing with the mapbox (ios/swift) `setVisibleCoordinateBounds` function to center the viewport of a map to the given BoundsCoords. [see api here](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.2.2/Classes/MGLMapView.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLMapView(im)setCenterCoordinate:zoomLevel:animated:)

It never set the exact Bounds or more specific it sets diffrent zoom levels whenever i call the function. the given boundsCoords are correct. Also tried setCenterCoordinate:zoomLevel:direction:animated:completionHandler cause i need an completionHandler. But it has the sam issues. Somebody experienced similar issues ?

Answer (score 2):

Use one of the methods that allows you to customize the edge padding, such as: [`-[MGLMapView setVisibleCoordinates:count:edgePadding:direction:duration:animationTimingFunction:completionHandler:]`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.2.2/Classes/MGLMapView.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLMapView(im)setVisibleCoordinates:count:edgePadding:direction:duration:animationTimingFunction:completionHandler:).

Set `edgePadding` to `UIEdgeInsetsZero`, if you don’t need any padding.

In the upcoming v3.3.0, there will be a [`-[MGLMapView cameraThatFitsCoordinateBounds:edgePadding:]`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/pull/4790) method, as well.

Comment: i did use that too. same strange behavior with the zoom level. made a small screencast. [see here](https://giphy.com/gifs/xT8qBgBh5xPJnQiOru)
guess i will calculate the center point of the boundingbox and set a camera animation to it. when is v.3.30 coming ?

Comment: v3.3 is [in beta now](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/releases/tag/ios-v3.3.0-beta.1) and should be finished sometime in the next month or so.