# setVisibleCoordinateBounds crops polygon when zooming out

Tags: ios, mapbox

I'm developing an iOS application where the user is able to tap on a property boundary and the mapView is supposed to set the visible bounds in the view to display the whole property - and then highlight the property boundaries. I'm using setVisibleCoordinateBounds with a completion handler that highlights the property boundaries after the animation is done.

```
func updateFieldBoundariesHighlightSourceShape(featureArray : [MGLMultiPolygonFeature]?) {
    if let fieldBoundariesSource = self.mapView.style?.source(withIdentifier: Coordinator.MapBoxIdentifier.fieldBoundaryHighlightSourceLayer.rawValue) as? MGLShapeSource {
        let features = featureArray ?? generateFieldBoundaryFeatureArray(fields: self.fields.map({$0}))
        let newShapeCollectionFeature = MGLShapeCollectionFeature(shapes: features)
        fieldBoundariesSource.shape = newShapeCollectionFeature
    }
}
```

```
func setHighlightedField(field: Field)
(...)
    self.mapView.setVisibleCoordinateBounds(fieldFeature.overlayBounds, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 65, left: 65, bottom: 65, right: 65), animated: true, completionHandler: {
        // After zooming and positioning field on the screen, add layers to the map's style.
        self.sceneStates.activeField = selectedField
        self.updateFieldBoundariesHighlightSourceShape(featureArray: [fieldFeature])
    })
(...)
}
```

This is a snippet of what I have. When the zoom is at a level that shows the whole property, it zooms in and everything is fine. The issue is, when zoomed in a small property and then selecting a larger one, zoom animation stops at some point (incomplete) and the highlight layer shows a cropped polygon compared to the property's real overlay bounds.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37596103/setvisiblecoordinatebounds-never-set-the-exact-bounds) question but none of the answers fixed the issue. It looks like MapBox is getting only the polygon/boundaries from a visible/nearby tile and cropping what is outside of that tile.

I've tried using the following approaches with identical results: mapView.fly(to:), cameraThatFitsCoordinateBounds and setVisibleCoordinates(using the polygon's point's coordinates as an array of unsafe pointers)

[Here is a GIF of what is going on](https://media.giphy.com/media/THUeI2esu3QGrS36k3/giphy.gif)